# How can I run a different command but with the same arguments?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

For example, I edit and then run the same source.

```
vim arbit.py
python arbit.py
```

I know I could run it from within `vim`, but I want a general solution on Bash. I keep finding situations where I reuse arguments.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `!*`.  It expands to all words except the first one (i.e. the command).

```
$ vim arbit.py
$ python !*
python arbit.py
```

You can combine it with all the features of `!`, for example:

```
$ vim arbit.py
$ ls
$ python !vim:*
vim arbit.py
```

Or, if you want only the last word, there are two other ways:

```
$ vim arbit.py
$ python !$
```

or:

```
$ vim arbit.py
$ python <Esc+.>
```

See the [bash history interaction documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) for more details.

Comment: With `!:2` you reuse the second argument of the previous command.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least a couple of ways to do this.

```
$ vim arbit.py
$ python[press Alt-.]
```

which retrieves the last argument of the previous command as does:

```
$ vim arbit.py
$ python !$
```

or

```
$ vim arbit.py
$ python !*
```

which retrieves all the arguments of the previous command.